# Select one of two iframes with no id in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, innerhtml

How do I select 1 of 2 iframes on page with the following code?

```
window.onload = function() {
   let frameElement = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   let doc = frameElement.contentDocument;
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.start-screen-search__sub-title:after {content: \' online below, or call: XXX\'; font-size: 22px;}</style>';
}
```

Comment: Without an ID, how do you know which of the two you want to select? The first one? Then just use `frameElement[0]` to reference that. The second? `frameElement[1]`. Some other criteria? We'll need to know what the criteria are to help further.

Comment: Why not just give them id's?

Comment: I am not able to give them id's as it's a widget and I don't have access to the code. Can you show me how to properly use frameElement[0] in the code please?

Comment: And it's the second iframe

Answer (score 1):

You can access the second iframe by index on your `frameElement` variable. Since you're using `getElementsByTagName`, you will have a node list of elements that you can access by index.

```js
window.onload = function() {
   let frameElement = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
   console.log('should be cnn.com iframe', frameElement[1]);
   let doc = frameElement[1].contentDocument || frameElement[1].contentWindow; // <-- select the 2nd iframe
   doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.start-screen-search__sub-title:after {content: \' online below, or call: XXX\'; font-size: 22px;}</style>';
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://yahoo.com"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://cnn.com"></iframe>
```

Here's a basic example of how to set html content within an iframe. (SOF doesn't allow you to do it in their code editor, so here's a js fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/hfy1mju7/1/

Comment: Now getting this error on console and JS CSS has no effect. SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "body" on cross-origin object

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're using a widget you need to first find an unique class or something this widget is giving you. This iframe may be wrapped inside of a `div` that has an unique class name to make your life easier when targeting the Iframe you need.

After you locate it, you can use `querySelectorAll` to get all the iframes:

```
const iframes = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
```

It will return you an array. Then you can choose which one you need:

```
iframes[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure how to incorporate this into the existing code I have. If you could show me the full code that would be helpful.

Comment: `let frameElement = document.querySelectorAll("iframe")[0]`. I'm using `[0]` as an example, you'd need to find which one you're looking for in your case.

Comment: Your request is very vague. You asked to how select an iframe and I provided an answer for it. Do you have a link or something to your project so we can debug it?